# ESP8266 latency via UDP

Tags: udp, esp8266, latency, esp32, low-latency

I create a simple setup of a master (ESP8266-12F) and a slave (ESP8266-01) and use UDP for data transmission. A message contains 4 bytes. I measured the time between the Master sends a request, and the Master gets the answer from the Slave via `micros()`.

The Problem is there is a latency increase from `2-4 [ms]` up to `25 [ms]` and more.

- To confirm that I remove all `Serial.prints()` perhaps a Serial Buffer problem, and I use as Signalindicator a digital Pin (High on Request and LOW if Answerpacket arrived) the Oscilloscope shows the same behaviour.
- Next Step I thought maybe a intern Buffer increase? So I watch the Heap to each signal but there seems no problem. Perhaps a static buffer only for the WiFi???.
- Next step I changed the interval-time of Masters request from `50 [ms]` to `1000 [ms]`, but still the same picture. Also a different CPU Clockfreq. (`80-160 MHz`) brings no changes.
  Pictures:

- [`Red:     80 MHz Request every 1000 ms`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6yWH.png)
- [`Blue:    80 MHz Request every   50 ms`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE2IH.png)
- [`Yellow: 160 MHz Request every 1000 ms`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgdaY.png)
- [`Green:  160 MHz Request every   50 ms`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqXIN.png)

- Afterwards I created a new nodemcu Firmeware (Modules: adc, file, gpio, i2c, net, node, spi, tmr, uart, wifi), but same behaviour…
- I thought it is a WiFi-Signal problem, so I tried some Metalshields around the ESPs, but this brings not the latency in it…
- Maybe a general WiFi-Modul problem, so I tried to write commands on an SD card and measure the time… And there was the same behaviour, but not so random. Now I think there are more than one or two reasons for the UDP latency.

---

### QUESTION:

Has anyone the same problems or have anyone experienced a behaviour similar to this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**Edit :** Added code

```
// Master (Send Request and waits for answer)
void loop(void) 
{
    delay(50);
    CallSensor(); 
    do{
        ;
    }while(!ListenClients());
}

void CallSensor(void)
{
    static long counter = 0;
    char     requestPacket[_SIZE_PACKET_] = {0x50,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    APlocal_IP[3] = SENSOR_FIELD[0][0];
    
    if(SENSOR_FIELD[0][0] != 1)
    {
        TIME_UDP_START = micros();
        digitalWrite(_PIN_LED_B_, HIGH);
        UDP.beginPacket(APlocal_IP, UDPPort);
        UDP.write(requestPacket);
        UDP.endPacket();
    }
}

bool ListenClients()
{
    static uint16_t     remport = 0;
    static IPAddress    remIP   = {0,0,0,0}; 
    char                incomingPacket[_SIZE_PACKET_] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

    if( UDP.parsePacket() && (UDP.read(incomingPacket, _SIZE_PACKET_) > 0) )
    {
        remIP   = UDP.remoteIP();
        remport = UDP.remotePort();
        
        if (SENSOR_FIELD[0][0] == remIP[3])
        {
            TIME_UDP_STOP = micros();
            digitalWrite(_PIN_LED_B_, LOW);
            Serial.printf(":%d\n",(TIME_UDP_STOP-TIME_UDP_START));
            return true;
        }
        else{return false;}
    }
    else{return false;}
}
```

```
// Slave (sends Value on Masters Request)
void loop(void) 
{
    ListenHost();
}

void ListenHost()
{
    static uint16_t     remport     = 0;
    static IPAddress    remIp       = {0,0,0,0};
    char    incomingPacket[_SIZE_PACKET_] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    
    if( UDP.parsePacket() && (UDP.read(incomingPacket, _SIZE_PACKET_) > 0))
    {
        SendAnswer();
    }
}

void SendAnswer(void)
{
    char     requestPacket[_SIZE_PACKET_] = {0x26,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    UDP.beginPacket(APlocal_IP, UDPPort);
    UDP.write(requestPacket);
    UDP.endPacket();    
}
```

Comment: Try disabling power saving. `#include <esp_wifi.h> WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); esp_wifi_set_ps (WIFI_PS_NONE);`

Comment: why do you measure with micros()?

Comment: @rustyx I see esp_wifi.h is a RTOS SDK lib. but we use in our Case NONOS SDK.

Comment: @Juraj we want to have a closer look to the system. Did you know any problems to meassure with micros()?

Comment: For NONOS try `wifi_set_sleep_type(NONE_SLEEP_T);` (btw, why are you using such a limited SDK? IMHO the overhead of FreeRTOS is negligible in comparison to the benefits it provides)

Comment: only problem with using micros is possible confusion of results with milllis

Comment: instead of measuring cpu jitter by applying millis in delay() go for a better function if you can that is working cycle accurate https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/37387/can-i-make-delaymicroseconds-more-accurate

Comment: @rustyx Sorry for the late answer... `wifi_set_sleep_type(NONE_SLEEP_T):` brings no improvement. Thanks for your Help.
Next Step is to change to RTOS but this take a while.